# How can I maintain a high res image in my Storyboard in Xcode without having it pixelate?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiimage

I'm making an app using Swift in Xcode. I have a few buttons and images on one of my View Controllers. I am using high resolution images, but I noticed that they pixelate to the point where it is visible to the naked eye. There are some questions that I have found pertaining to the resizing of images, but none regarding immediate pixelization. I was hoping someone could help. Below are two images. The first is an image (a screenshot) from my app and the second is an image (also a screenshot) from another app that is not mine. The icon on the other app is smaller, but despite this is less pixelated.

[image: My App]
[image: Other App]

Comment: Are you creating @2x and @3x assets? And when you say "High Res" do you mean "large size dimensions"? Because `size != resolution` and it doesn't make much sense to use very large images for a very small icon.

Comment: @JakeG It is a relatively high resolution as well as a large size. I do not have a 2x or an 3x yet, but I am planning on adding them

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using svg instead of jpg (lossy) or png(lossless)? It would seem that this would be the way to go, since you can expand to perfect definition on all resizing screens. svg uses code instead of an image format that can be lossy and given the examples you have posted would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use paint code for more easy worked , with paint code you can export svg

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to increase the dpi